# Quicktime Directshow Filters

Tags: directshow, quicktime

I'm looking into DirectShow Source Filters for playing QuickTime media. Can anyone who has been down the same path offer any advice?

I've tested offerings from MediaLooks and RogueStream. Are there any others I should check out? Are there any free or open source alternatives?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

We had good experience using the RogueStream filter for transcoding, so I'd go with that one.

Comment: I did some basic testing in GraphEditPlus and The RogueStream filter had noticeable performance deficiencies compared to MediaLooks for Real Time Video & Audio playback. What was your filter used for? (if you don't mind me asking) Where you only using it to convert file formats?